# Qual a diferença entre as propriedades 'outline' e 'border'?

Tags: css

Estudando a propriedade `outline`, percebi que ela produz o mesmo efeito da propriedade `border`, pelo menos aparentemente, vejam:

```css
.span1{
   outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.span2{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="span1">outline</span>
<span class="span2">border</span>
```

**Minha dúvida é:** qual a diferença entre ambas em questão de uso, compatibilidade e propriedades internas da cada uma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas diferenças entre os dois, mas o principal em questão é a acessibilidade, pois o `Outline` é para dar um *feedback* visual para o usuário quando o campo está focado. E diferente da resposta do colega vc **NUNCA** deve tira esse *feedback* do seu usuário, e lembres-se, nem todos utilizam mouse para navegar, então o `:hover` não é para todos. Então usar apenas o `:hover` para estilizar uma borda quando passar o mouse não é uma opção muito inclusiva. Sugiro que leia esse artigo http://www.outlinenone.com/

Tirando isso existem outras particularidades do `outline`. Ele não é padrão e pode ser diferente dependendo do `user-agent` do browser, diferente do `border` ele é nativo e qq campo que seja focavel, como elementos de `form` já vêm com o `outline` setado de forma padrão, e é ativado tando clicando com o mouse quanto sendo acessado com o `Tab` do teclado. Então o Safari, o Opera, o Edge, etc, qualquer um deles pode tratar o `outline` de forma diferente. O Opera mesmo até pouco tempo tinha o `outline` com cantos arredondados, e a cor do `outline` no Safari e Chrome eram diferentes. Esses "estilos" eram definidos pelo `user-agent`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Falando da parte técnica existem algumas diferenças tb, essa são as propriedades do `outline`

- outline-style
- outline-color
- outline-width
- outline-offset
- outline

O `outline-offset` por exemplo não exite na borda, e ela serve para dizer o tanto que o "contorno" vai se distanciar do elemento, porém esse valor pode ser positivo ou negativo caso vc quera o `outline` mais para dentro do elemento. E isso leva a outra ponto **importantíssimo**!

O `outline` não faz parte do `box-model`, ou seja ele não ocupa espaço de renderização... Isso significa que mesmo que vc coloca seu `outline` com 20px ele não vai "empurrar" os elementos ao lado, pois ele não ocupa espaço na tela, é o mesmo que acontece com o `box-shadow`, ele não ocupa espaço físico na tela. Já o `border` se vc colocar 20px de `border-width` ou vc vai precisar usa `box-sizing` ou essa borada vai empurrar tudo que estiver ao redor, pois ela vai tomar 20px de espaço ao redor do elemento.

Veja o exemplo abaixo, a linha vermelha é o `outline`, ela não empurra a `div` de baixo com a borda preta. E a linha vermelha está distante 5px do elemento por causa do `outline-offset`

```css
.box  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 20px dashed red;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Propriedades do `Border`

- border
- border-color
- border-radius
- border-style
- border-width
- border-image
- border-image-slice
- border-collapse
- etc...

Além disso vc pode tratar individualmente cada um dos lados da borda, colocando uma cor para cada lado ou uma espessura pada cada borda, com `outline` vc não consegue fazer isso. Assim como vc não consegue usar `border-radius` ou `border-image` no `outline`

- border-left
- border-top
- border-bottom
- border-right

```css
.box  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 5px dashed red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid pink;
  border-left: 4px dotted blue;
  border-right: 10px double green;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Tratando Borda com o Foco

Se vc quiser customizar o `:focus` de um `input` por exemplo vc é livre para isso, pois o importante é o feedback para o usuário de que o campo está ativo. *Só vou deixar uma observação abaixo quanto ao **SEO**, então se vc fizer alguma mudança desse tipo em um site é bom acompanhar os resultados pela Analytics...*

Vc pode usar a pseudo classe :focus para tratar o input que estiver em foco, substituindo o `outline`. Se vc quiser vc pode até ter um :hover tb como fiz nesse exemplo. Então vc tem 3 estados aqui, sem foco, com hover e focado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.x:hover  {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.x:focus  {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="" class="x">
```

---

**Sobre SEO**

Falando em **SEO**, tenha em mente que a não existe semântica ou SEO feitos com CSS, o que existe aqui é um tratamento visual para melhorar o UX, e a UX sim e considerada como fator de ranqueamento, então se o Google considerar campos sem `outline:none` como ponto negativo vc pode ser prejudicado. Isso é apenas uma hipótese...

Comment: Massa!!  :D 

Comment: @Sam é é nois 

Answer (score 0):

Bom, o Outline funciona apenas quando o input ou campo está em foco, e até onde eu sei, você não pode mudar muitas características dele quanto pode mudar no Border. Já o Border, é como o próprio nome diz, uma Borda que fica em volta do elemento mesmo se este não estiver em foco, onde você pode estilizar de maneira com que esta seja mais arrendondada, quadrada e até outros formatos com a propriedade do `border-radius`. Além de que, nessa situação, é muito melhor de se utilizar e estilizar o Border para ocasiões como `:hover`,`:active` e dai por diante. Eu particularmente quase nunca deixo o Outline ativo nos meus projetos, pois se já alguma Border, o Outline fica sobre a mesma com uma forma quadrada, o que acaba deixando o campo "feio".